# Laravel simply won't find my class

Tags: laravel

Laravel keeps telling me that my class isn't found and I'm pretty sure I've exhausted any solution.

Route:

```
Route::get('/custom-reports/timezone', array( 'uses' => 'Controllers\Reports\TimezoneController@generate'));
```

Directories:

```
app/controllers/Reports/TimezoneController.php
```

TimzoneController.php

```
<?php 
namespace Controllers\Reports;
use Controllers\BaseController;

class TimezoneController extends BaseController
{
    public function generate() {}
}
```

Composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/libraries",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Error:

```
ReflectionException -1
Class Controllers\Reports\TimezoneController does not exist
```

**I have already done php composer dump-autoload**

Comment: try renaming directory name to Controllers and run dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classmap` doesn't support namespacing (as far as I know) so you need to setup a PSR-4 autoloader.

Change your `composer.json` to this and run `composer dump-autoload`. It should work after that.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "files": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Controllers\\": "app/controllers"
    }
},
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but I have several other directories and class's in my app that work in this structure, without adding the psr-4 bit. Not sure how they are working properly. :L